# How can I cover a wood stove pipe where it passes through the second floor?

Tags: woodstove

I live on 2nd floor of wood stove house. Exposed pipe runs through my room (I know it's not code...it's not my house).  It gets way too warm and there's a smell... Please tell me there is something I can wrap around the pipe to solve my problem.

Comment: Since you mentioned a smell, you may want to get that flue checked out and insulated.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the flue pipe runs through your room. This pipe should definitely be insulated, not only for comfort, but for safety as well. Insulating the pipe keeps the heat in the pipe, preventing the buildup of creosote, which is a fire hazard.

You will need to wrap that pipe with high-temperature insulation made specifically for that purpose. Do not use anything not specifically rated and designed for insulating metal chimney liners. However, this may not be a DIY job. Combustion appliances and ventilation are serious business. You may want to hire a pro.

Answer (score 1):

The flue pipe should have a double wall.  Cool air comes down outside, while hot air goes up center.  This provides safety from leaks in flue because outside is under negative pressure so it goes back down into firebox.  This also provides makeup air for firebox so you are not pulling cold air in from all over the house.

This is a standard part available for purchase.

You should check with a licensed professional before doing this type of DIY installation.  A mis-step or oversight, could be life threatening.